# Unity build only shows a gray screen

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a multiplayer first-person shooter, in the editor, I can play fine but when I build it, it just shows a gray screen and nothing happens. unity doesn't show any error after building.

i'm using unity 2020.1.6f1 and HDRP + DRX

my pc specs are:
AMD Ryzen 5 2600 Six-Core Processor
Nvidia GeForce GT 1030

[this is the main menu in the editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MFGE.png)

[this is the build, it should show the main menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9np4Q.png)

Comment: Did you add the correct scene in the build screen in the correct order?

Answer (score 0):

You can try enabling `Development Build` from build settings to access the development console in the standalone application. Alternatively you can check the [log files](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/Manual/LogFiles.html) for the application for any errors that only happen in the build.

**Based on current documentation you can find the log files from:**

- **Windows:** %USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow\CompanyName\ProductName\Player.log
- **Mac:** ~/Library/Logs/Company Name/Product Name/Player.log
- **Linux:** ~/.config/unity3d/CompanyName/ProductName/Player.log

Comment: Then I would try to debug are corrects scenes are getting loaded in the build by adding new gameobject to each scene that logs "Scene loaded: SceneName" and "Scene unloaded: SceneName" on OnEnable and OnDisable. If issue is somewhere else and scenes are properly getting loaded you could add debug script that allows you to change camera + rendering settings with F1, F2 or whatever to see if HDRP + DRX stuff is causing you issues.

Comment: Also if you're using multiple cameras i.e one for the game and one for the UI then I recommend disabling one or the other to see if they conflict with the rendering someway. I recall having problems with HDRP and `Canvas Render mode: Screen Space - Camera`